# Are there any downsides in using C++ for network daemons?

Tags: c++, c, networking, daemon

I've been writing a number of network daemons in different languages over the past years, and now I'm about to start a new project which requires a new custom implementation of a properitary network protocol.

The said protocol is pretty simple - some basic JSON formatted messages which are transmitted in some basic frame wrapping to have clients know that a message arrived completely and is ready to be parsed.

The daemon will need to handle a number of connections (about 200 at the same time) and do some management of them and pass messages along, like in a chat room.

In the past I've been using mostly C++ to write my daemons. Often with the Qt4 framework (the network parts, not the GUI parts!), because that's what I also used for the rest of the projects and it was simple to do and very portable. This usually worked just fine, and I didn't have much trouble.

Being a Linux administrator for a good while now, I noticed that most of the network daemons in the wild are written in plain C (of course some are written in other languages, too, but I get the feeling that > 80% of the daemons are written in plain C).

**Now I wonder why that is.** 
Is this due to a pure historic UNIX background (like KISS) or for plain portability or reduction of bloat? What are the reasons to *not* use C++ or any "higher level" languages for things like daemons?

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Update 1:

For me using C++ usually is more convenient because of the fact that I have *objects* which have getter and setter methods and such. Plain C's "context" objects can be a real pain at some point - especially when you are used to object oriented programming.

Yes, I'm aware that <del>C++ is a superset of C, and that C code is basically C++</del> you can compile any C code with a C++ compiler. But that's not the point. ;)

---

#### Update 2:

I'm aware that nowadays it might make more sense to use a high level (scripting) language like Python, node.js or similar. I did that in the past, and I know of the benefits of doing that (at least I hope I do ;) - but this question is just about C and C++.

Comment: I'd rather use something even more high level, since code execution vulnerabilities are much more likely in C/C++ than in languages with a safer memory model. The downside is that those typically have a higher RAM consumption.

Comment: I took a few looks at *node.js*, Python and some other languages. But most of them are either "too much" or have some other downside like lack of portability, lack of extensibility and so on...

Comment: That assertion is false. The problem is people who write C code in C++. The frameworks in C++ allow extremely leak proof code to be developed, if they are just used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I for one can't think of any technical reason to chose C over C++.  Not one that I can't instantly think of a counterpoint for anyway.

Edit in reply to edit: I would seriously discourage you from considering, "...C code is basically C++."  Although you can technically compile any C program with a C++ compiler (in as far as you don't use any feature in C that's newer than what C++ has adopted) I really try to discourage anyone from writing C like code in C++ or considering C++ as "C with objects."

In response to C being standard in Linux, only in as far as C developers keep saying it :p  C++ is as much part of any standard in Linux as C is and there's a huge variety of C++ programs made on Linux.  If you're writing a Linux driver, you need to be doing it in C.  Beyond that...I know RMS likes to say you're more likely to find a C compiler than a C++ one but that hasn't actually been true for quite a long time now.  You'll find both or neither on almost all installations.

In response to maintainability - I of course disagree.

Like I said, I can't think of one that can't instantly be refuted.  Visa-versa too really.

Comment: Alright. I was always wondering if it had technical background. But from my feeling I'd say that C++ compilers (especially g++) are available and stable on most platforms.

Comment: But if you write your daemon in C you can use the words 'new' and 'delete' as variable names.  Can't really refute the sheer awesomeness of that now can you?

Comment: Ha! That was the argument I was waiting for. I always wanted to use *new* and *delete* as variable names. ;)

Comment: hehehe there's actually been a couple of times when I've just done that, especially with parameter names.  One time in particular I had a signal representing a switch from one value to the other.  Wanted reciever to have access to both: `void value_changed(id old, id new)`

Answer (score 6):

The resistance to C++ for the development for daemon code stem from a few sources:

- C++ has a reputation for being hard to avoid memory leaks. And memory leaks are a no no in any long running software. This is to a degree untrue - the problem is developers with a C background tend to use C idioms in C++, and that is very leaky. Using the available C++ features like vectors and smart pointers can produce leak free code.
- As a converse, the smart pointer template classes, while they hide resource allocation and deallocation from the programmer, do a lot of it under the covers. In fact C++ generally has a lot of implicit allocation as a result of copy constructors and so on. As a result the C++ heap can become fragmented over time and daemon processes will eventually fail with an out of memory error even though there is sufficient RAM. This can be ameliorated by the use of modern heap managers that are more fragmenttation resistant, but they do this by consuming more resource up front.
- while this doesn't apply to usermode daemon code, kernel mode developers avoid C++, again because of the implicit code C++ generates, and the exceptions C++ libraries use to handle errors. Most c++ compilers implement c++ exceptions in terms of hardware exceptions, and lots of kernel mode code is executed in environments where exceptions are not allowed to be thrown. Also, all the implicit code generated by c++, being implicit, cannot be wrapped in #pragma directives to guarantee its placement in pageable, or non pageable memory.

As a result, C++ is not possible for kernel development on any platform at all, and generally shunned by daemon developers too. Even if one's code is written using the proper smart memory management classes and does not leak - keeping on top of potential memory fragmentation issues makes languages where memory allocation is explicit a preferred choice.

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it is largely correct and quite good but in fact it is possible to do kernel development in C++ on at least one platform.  The Mac OS X IOKit is written entirely in C++ and you _must_ use C++ to write drivers, though exceptions and RTTI are disabled.

Comment: I disagree that C++ without exceptions can still be called C++. nonetheless, thanks for that update. I still wonder how they solved the difficulty tagging implicit code as non page-able.

Comment: This. It's possible to use C++ for kernel code if you use a subset of C++, and it's advisable to write daemons in C++ if you know what you are doing... but that goes for anything. I also liked this answer. It explains why some are hesitant without making the C daemon coders like complete luddites.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend whichever you feel more comfortable with. If you are more comfortable with C++, your code is going to be cleaner, and run more efficiently, as you'll be more used to it, if you know what I mean.

The same applies on a larger scale to something like a Python vs Perl discussion. Whichever you are more comfortable with will probably produce better code, because you'll have experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that ANSI C is the standard programming language in Linux. It is important to follow this standard whenever people want to share their code with others etc. But it is not a requirement if you just want to write something for yourself.

You personally can use C or C++ and the result will be identical. I think you should choose C++ if you know it well and can exploit some special object oriented features of it in your code. Don't look too much to other people here, if you are good in C++ just go and write your daemon in C++. I would personally write it in C++ as well.

Comment: Thanks. So that might probably one of the main reasons every one is using plain C for most Linux stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.  The reason for *not* using C++ is KISS, particularly if you ever intend for someone else to maintain your code down the road.  Most folks that I know of learned to write daemons from existing source or reading books by Stevens.  Pretty much that means your examples will be in C.  C++ is just fine, I've written daemons in it myself, but I think if you expect it to be maintained and you don't know who the maintainer might be down the road it shows better foresight to write in C.

Comment: I'll amend this post to sheepishly admit that for any program, daemon or not, that I expect to be more than a few thousand lines of code or so I'm going to use C++ and organize my code into objects ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Boost makes it incredibly easy to write single threaded, or multi-threaded and highly scalable, networking daemons with the [asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using C++, with a reservation on using exception handling and dynamic RTTI. These features may have run time performance cost implications and may not be supported well across platforms.

C++ is more modular and maintainable so if you can avoid these features go ahead and use it for your project.

Comment: Never really used RTTI and exceptions very much in C++. Not sure if it's just me, but they feel slightly icky. But maybe I should spend a few hours in my C++ book to get some grip on them...

Answer (score 0):

Both C and C++ are perfectly suited for the task of writing daemons.

Besides that, nowadays, you should consider also scripting languages as Perl or Python. Performance is usually just good enough and you will be able to write applications more robust and in less time.

BTW, take a look at [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html), a framework for writting portable network applications in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly take a look at ACE. Like I commented above, I *did* write some daemons in Python, PHP and node.js before and I know of the benefits of doing so. However, my original question was regarding C and C++. :)